# IIS Manager 8.5 not applying Mime Types

Tags: windows, iis, server

I am running a web server with windows 2012 and IIS Manager 8.5.

When I am going to browse a .gpx file on my web folder I get an Error 500 (500 21 13), so I registered the mime type and restarted the web server. No changes - still no chance to get this file opened. When it ends with .txt there is no problem, but it won't recognize .gpx. Why could this be?

Thanks a lot
Chris